# Only drop duplicates if number of duplicates is less than X

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to drop duplicate rows in my DataFrame only if the number of duplicates is less than x (e.g. 3)
(if more than 3 duplicates, keep them !)

Sample:

where `count` is number of duplicates and duplicates are in col `data`

```
data | count
-------------
a    | 1
b    | 2
b    | 2
c    | 1
d    | 3
d    | 3
d    | 3
```

Desired result:

```
data | count
-------------
a    | 1
b    | 1
c    | 1
d    | 3
d    | 3
d    | 3
```

How can i achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is `b=1` in output?

Comment: Because there's only one left after dropping the duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could do the following:

```
# create mask for non-duplicates and groups larger than 3
mask = (df.groupby('data')['count'].transform('count') >= 3) | ~df.duplicated('data')

# filter
filtered = df.loc[mask].drop('count', axis=1)

# reset count column
filtered['count'] = filtered.groupby('data')['data'].transform('count')

print(filtered)
```

**Output**

```
  data  count
0    a      1
1    b      1
3    c      1
4    d      3
5    d      3
6    d      3
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need chain conditions with [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and get greater or equal values of `N` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), last set `1` for `count` column:

```
N = 3
df1 = df[~df.duplicated('data') | df['count'].ge(N)].copy()
df1.loc[df['count'] < N, 'count'] = 1
print (df1)
  data  count
0    a      1
1    b      1
3    c      1
4    d      3
5    d      3
6    d      3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
N = 3
df['count'] = df['count'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x < N else x)
result = pd.concat([df[df['count'].eq(1)].drop_duplicates(), df[df['count'].eq(N)]])
```

result

```
 data  count
0   a   1
1   b   1
3   c   1
4   d   3
5   d   3
6   d   3
```